# Two different kind of stops for network analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I have a network dataset all set up and I'm able to add various stops.

However, I can only add one kind of 'stop'. I'd like to have two separate stops, in this case, ambulance stations and care homes.

This would then allow me to find the total drive time from my ambulance station to the 30+ care homes on my network dataset.

Is there a way to have two different kind of stops?

Comment: Are they both stops,  it sounds like one is your facilities (start location) and the other is your orders (stop location).  Ie they always start at an ambulance station (so using network analyst the station is your facility) and the care homes will be your order locations since they are stopping there.

Comment: Yes that's right. I was using the 'New Route' function when it makes much more sense to use 'New Closest Facility' function. This would be a better function to use wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure you should be using the Closest Facility (I am not at my work pc and its been awhile since I used network analyst)  Here is a great tutorial from esri on the subject: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/network-analyst-tutorial.pdf I think you want to do what they show in chapter 4.

Comment: @ed-hankins It sounds like you are on the right track so I think you should write your comments up as an answer